# Understanding control flow of nested for loops sans break statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, nested-loops, break

I'm trying to understand now what's happening here, but why the control flow of nested loops in Python work they way they do in this particular scenario:

```
# let's say that `res` is a list of dictionaries where len(res) == 20

for index, item in enumerate(res):
        print index,item
        for key, value in item.iteritems():
            id = item.get('id')
            print id
            video_asset_ids.append(id)
           # break
```

The output of the above nested loops looks like this:

```
0 {u'updated_at': u'2012-09-18T22:07:37.027Z', u'account_id': u'2001', u'duration': 232410, u'text_tracks': [], u'images': {u'poster': {u'asset_id': u'34343615001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}, u'thumbnail': {u'asset_id': u'34343614001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}}, u'digital_master_id': None, u'custom_fields': {}, u'schedule': {u'starts_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'ends_at': None}, u'id': u'34351747001', u'state': u'ACTIVE', u'cue_points': [], u'sharing': {u'source_id': None, u'to_external_acct': True, u'by_id': None, u'by_reference': False, u'by_external_acct': False}, u'complete': True, u'tags': [u'football', u'nfl network nfl films football', u'tv', u'sports', u'pro', u'entertainment'], u'link': None, u'reference_id': u'1578699', u'geo': None, u'name': u'Video: Inside NFL Films', u'created_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'economics': u'AD_SUPPORTED', u'original_filename': None, u'folder_id': None}
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
4416825569001
1 {u'updated_at': u'2012-09-18T22:07:37.027Z', u'account_id': u'2001', u'duration': 232410, u'text_tracks': [], u'images': {u'poster': {u'asset_id': u'34343615001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}, u'thumbnail': {u'asset_id': u'34343614001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}}, u'digital_master_id': None, u'custom_fields': {}, u'schedule': {u'starts_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'ends_at': None}, u'id': u'34351747001', u'state': u'ACTIVE', u'cue_points': [], u'sharing': {u'source_id': None, u'to_external_acct': True, u'by_id': None, u'by_reference': False, u'by_external_acct': False}, u'complete': True, u'tags': [u'football', u'nfl network nfl films football', u'tv', u'sports', u'pro', u'entertainment'], u'link': None, u'reference_id': u'1578699', u'geo': None, u'name': u'Video: Inside NFL Films', u'created_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'economics': u'AD_SUPPORTED', u'original_filename': None, u'folder_id': None}
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
34351747001
```

etc, etc

Obviously when we add a `break` statement to the nested loop, the `id` object is only printed out once, and the output looks like this:

```
0 {u'updated_at': u'2012-09-18T22:07:37.027Z', u'account_id': u'2001', u'duration': 232410, u'text_tracks': [], u'images': {u'poster': {u'asset_id': u'34343615001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}, u'thumbnail': {u'asset_id': u'34343614001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}}, u'digital_master_id': None, u'custom_fields': {}, u'schedule': {u'starts_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'ends_at': None}, u'id': u'34351747001', u'state': u'ACTIVE', u'cue_points': [], u'sharing': {u'source_id': None, u'to_external_acct': True, u'by_id': None, u'by_reference': False, u'by_external_acct': False}, u'complete': True, u'tags': [u'football', u'nfl network nfl films football', u'tv', u'sports', u'pro', u'entertainment'], u'link': None, u'reference_id': u'1578699', u'geo': None, u'name': u'Video: Inside NFL Films', u'created_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'economics': u'AD_SUPPORTED', u'original_filename': None, u'folder_id': None}
4416825569001
1 {u'updated_at': u'2012-09-18T22:07:37.027Z', u'account_id': u'2001', u'duration': 232410, u'text_tracks': [], u'images': {u'poster': {u'asset_id': u'34343615001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}, u'thumbnail': {u'asset_id': u'34343614001', u'width': None, u'height': None}]}}, u'digital_master_id': None, u'custom_fields': {}, u'schedule': {u'starts_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'ends_at': None}, u'id': u'34351747001', u'state': u'ACTIVE', u'cue_points': [], u'sharing': {u'source_id': None, u'to_external_acct': True, u'by_id': None, u'by_reference': False, u'by_external_acct': False}, u'complete': True, u'tags': [u'football', u'nfl network nfl films football', u'tv', u'sports', u'pro', u'entertainment'], u'link': None, u'reference_id': u'1578699', u'geo': None, u'name': u'Video: Inside NFL Films', u'created_at': u'2009-08-18T00:53:17.569Z', u'economics': u'AD_SUPPORTED', u'original_filename': None, u'folder_id': None}
34351747001
```

etc, etc

So without the break statement, how are these loops functioning in terms of control flow (or on the sack)? Why is it that, without the `break` statement, the nested loops keeps printing out the same `id` object a number of times equal to the number of items in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through `item.iteritems()` goes through every `key, value` pair in the dictionary, so you are printing the same ID for every pair. You don't need the inner loop at all. Try this:

```
for index, item in enumerate(res):
    print index,item
    id = item.get('id')
    print id
    video_asset_ids.append(id)
```

Answer (score 1):

On each iteration of your inner loop, `key` and `value` should be different but `item` is the same. `item` changes with each iteration of your **outer** loop.

Since you are getting `id` from `item`, then `id` will not change on each inner iteration.

Perhaps you should be getting the `id` from `key` or `value`.